# How bad is it to run arbitrary queries on Mongo collections

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm thinking about allowing users to enter custom JSON queries which will directly be parsed into a python dict and passed as the `filter` argument of pymongo [collections's find](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=collection%20find#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) method. The only validation will be on the validness of the JSON data provided. All the exceptions raised by the `find` method will be caught and handled.

My concerns are,

- Can the user manipulate (i.e update or delete) data from the collection?
- Can the user access data from other collections?
- Is this a bad idea?

The other option would be I write an extensive JSON Schema specifying what kind of keys, operators and values are allowed.

Comment: Compared to SQL it's probably a lot safer, since you specify the basic action being performed (e.g. `find` and not `insert`), but at the very least you'll probably still run the risk of a DoS attack if a user can provide arbitrarily complex and costly queries.

Comment: And I'm not entirely sure, but `$where` will probably allow arbitrary Javascript execution… https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/

Comment: Maybe you need to be more precise on the context too. Is their a collection that is shared between mutliple users ? Is there documents that must stay private ? Is there read only collections ? Are the databases separated or do you want to do it on only one database ?